# How can I hide credentials in a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, security, password

I need to pass credentials via curl to a database from several thousand systems, as each are updated.  A team who will not be permitted the credentials shall be executing the script.  Therefore, I want to hide username/password from the update team.

Comment: So the credentials are coming from these several thousand systems to a central location, or is it the other way around?

Comment: You could obfuscate the program, so that they can't read anything from it.

Comment: Are you even using https? Cause it would be meaningless to start an effort to secure username and password from your "team"(that you do not trust),  if it could be easily obtained by any network sniffing tool... Also, what is the problem to have a function in your database that will "run as" only this specific functions? could you expose a url without credentials, but limit by ip address or other parameters that will better identify your servers?

Answer (score 3):

> A team who will not be permitted the credentials shall be executing the script.

Essentially impossible. If this team will not be permitted to access the credentials, then the script that they run under their own account will also not be able to access the credentials. Or if the script can do so, then the humans also can, by replicating whatever it is the script does.

Have you considered giving them access to an RPC to a server that listens and has access to the credentials that does whatever they need to do (and only what they need to do)? Or use `sudo` to let them run this script, and only this script, under a privileged account (in this case, make sure the script cannot be made to do anything wrong by passing it different arguments)?